# QWidget's grab method doesn't work on a QVTKRenderWindowInteractor object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, screenshot, vtk

Using pyqt (Python3.7, on Ubuntu 18.04), I've created a GUI in which I render some VTK stuff that I want to create a video of. Therefore, I need to Qwidget.grab() the main window and save it to a png file (so I can assemble the images to a video file). 
This works fine for everything on the window (include QWidgets like sliders, combobox, etc. and matplotlib images) except for the rendered VTK object (QVTKRenderWindowInteractor) as it replaces it in the picture into a black box or sometime white noise.

I've made a minimal example of the problem, hoping that it was the complexity of the whole program that was the main problem. Unfortunately, even for minimal code, it still does not render the VTK part of the window.

Here is a minimal example of my problem, where clicking on the "Print" button should grab the image and save it to a PNG file.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout,QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication
import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor


def print_screen_callback(w):
    w.grab().save("non_satisfying_printed_window.png")


# Create a small interface that show a cylinder and allow to print it to a PNG file
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.show()
lay = QVBoxLayout()
w.setLayout(lay)

# Create and populate the vtk widget
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
w_vtk = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
lay.addWidget(w_vtk)
w_vtk.Initialize()
w_vtk.Start()
w_vtk.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(ren)
cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinder.SetResolution(8)
cylinderMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cylinderMapper.SetInputConnection(cylinder.GetOutputPort())
cylinderActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cylinderActor.SetMapper(cylinderMapper)
ren.AddActor(cylinderActor)

# Add print screen button
but = QPushButton("Print")
lay.addWidget(but)
but.released.connect(lambda: print_screen_callback(w))

# Run the application
app.exec()
```

The expected output is of course the actual window when the person presses on the button "Print".

Comment: This works for me:
`screen = self.PrintWidget.grab() image = QImage(screen) image.save("view.png")`

Not exactly sure if this is your problem.

Comment: Hi @JareBear
Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this gives the same gibberish for the main window as my snippet does.

Comment: For the main window its: `screen = self.grab()...`

Comment: ```def print_widget(self):
        # Create printer
        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        # Create painter
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        # Start painter
        painter.begin(printer)
        # Grab a widget you want to print
        screen = self.grab()
        # Draw grabbed pixmap
        painter.drawPixmap(10, 10, screen)
        # End painting
        painter.end()
```

Could you try and use `QPainter` with `QPrinter` like this?

Comment: Thanks again for your help
The previous snippet actually doesn't work but seems to be related to something else. I get the following error message : 
`QPainter::begin(): Returned false`
`QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted`

I will try to add a picture of the gibbering that I am talking about :)

[![gibbersh][1]][https://i.ibb.co/W0xjwTS/view.png]

Comment: You'r welcome!. I get the same issue on windows computers, but not on Linux, I have no idea what the issue is with that error. But, I only get it on Windows.